# Как из другого класса изменить элемент формы java

Tags: java

Есть два класса **Form** и **Checked**. В классе Form есть Label и кнопка. По нажатию кнопки создаю экземпляр класса Checked и запускаю его поток . ***Далее  мне нужно из класса Checked передать и изменить текст в Label, но никак не могу это сделать.***

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


import java.io.IOException;


public class MainForm extends Application {


    protected static int intVerifiedNews = 0;

    Button btnPlay = new Button("кнопка");


    Label lbVerifiedNews = new Label("Проверенно новостей: ");


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {




        final BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        final HBox hbox = addHBox();


        Scene scene = new Scene(border, 850, 500, Color.BLACK);


        btnPlay.setPrefSize(100, 24);
        btnPlay.setMinSize(24, 24);


        btnPlay.setOnAction((event) -> {

                    Checked ch = new Checked();
                    ch.start();

                }
        );


        border.setTop(hbox);

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btnPlay, lbVerifiedNews);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    private HBox addHBox() {

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5));
        return hbox;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

Втророй класс:

```
public class Checked extends Thread {


    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    MainForm.intVerifiedNews ++;
//Здесь нужно передать  значение intVerifiedNews в Label  
                System.out.println(MainForm.intVerifiedNews);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Передавайте ссылку класса Form в класс Checked и дергаете необходимые методы

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov
я пробовал создавать конструктор и передавать ссылку, но у меня все равно ничего не получилось. Как это правильно сделать?